# Equivalent of Visual Studio Property Sheets in Netbeans/Linux

Tags: c++, visual-studio, netbeans

I am used to working on Windows Visual Studio and a very helpful feature there was Property Sheets. These can be generically stored in any folder and can be used to setup project properties in any subsequent project/solution.

Suppose I wanted to use boost libraries, I would create a property sheet named `boost.props` in `c:\` and store in this the "Additional Include Directories" and the "Additional Library Directories" pertaining to boost installation in my computer. Then, in any project I would work on later that needs boost libraries, I can go to View->Property Manager and add `boost.props` into any of the configurations I would need, such as Win32|Debug or Win64|Release, etc. This saves the time of having to go to the Project Properties in every new solution/project and have to add these directories manually.

In Netbeans IDE for Linux, is there anything that is equivalent such that I can setup these directories once and then import them instead of having to setup a project every time with preprocessor definitions, additional library and include directories, etc?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Have you tried the netbeans cnd mailing list (here https://netbeans.org/community/lists/top.html)?

Comment: I have been googling this question for a week now of no avail. Looks like I would have to try the option you specified. Thanks.